# How to get list of routes in laravel test case?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

Like the the title suggest how to get list of routes in a test case. I know that it can be done in controllers by using `Route::getRoutes()`. But, this will not work in test cases. Can somebody give me an idea on this.

Update:

How can I do this in test cases?

```
$routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
$routeArray = [];
$i = 0
foreach($routeCollection as $value) {
    $routeArray[$i++] = $value->getPath();
}
```

Update 2:
Like this test case. I want to get a list of route in the test case. But this does not work.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

use Laracasts\Integrated\Extensions\Selenium as IntegrationTest;

class RouteTest extends IntegrationTest
{
    /**
    * A basic test example.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();

        foreach($routeCollection as $value) {
            $this->visit($value->getPath())
                 ->onPage($value->getPath());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/testing#calling-routes-from-tests there is a note that says:

**Note: Route filters are disabled when in the testing environment. To enable them, add Route::enableFilters() to your test.**

*PD:This is for 4.2.*

Comment: $this->call('GET', 'user/profile')
This method calls for a specific route, in this case 'user/profile'.

What I was looking for is to get all the list of routes in the project.

Comment: So... just like `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Just like this code.

$routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();

foreach($routeCollection as $value) {
    echo $value->getPath().'<br>';
}

Comment: Using "Route::enableFilters()" didn't solve anything?

Comment: @vivek - can you share more code with the above code also included?